# Combine two rows in a table to one with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write an SQL query (in Oracle DB) which performs the following:

Table:

```
Id | Name  | Father_id

1  | John  | 2
2  | Peter |
3  | Ann   | 2
```

Expected result:

```
Name  | Father_Name

John    Peter
Ann     Peter
```

I would like to list all the people who have a father in one row with the father's name. The user can have (of course) max. one father, but has not neccessarily one.

Which would be the best way to write such a query?

Comment: Do a self join.

Comment: Join the table with itself on `father_id == id`

Comment: in this day and age, we can have many fathers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self join, if you want fatherless children, do a left outer join

```
select *
from table t_child join 
     table t_father on t_child.father_id = t_father.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sql it will definatlly work

```
select child.MenuName as ChildName,parent.MenuName as ParentName from table_name as child
left join table_name as parent on child.parentId = parent.MenuId
```

you need to use left because you mention that not necessarily one

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a self-join (and two table/index scans) and can instead do it with a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71dc57/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE people ( Id, Name, Father_id ) AS
SELECT 1, 'John',  2    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Peter', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Ann',   2    FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name,
       PRIOR name AS father_name
FROM   people
WHERE  LEVEL > 1
OR     CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 0     -- Comment out if you do not want Peter,NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = father_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71dc57/11/0)**:

```
|  NAME | FATHER_NAME |
|-------|-------------|
| Peter |      (null) |
|  John |       Peter |
|   Ann |       Peter |
```